# Why does magnetic field lines go from plus to minus?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

My question is why the magnetic field lines goes from plus to minus, if there was two charge. Is it true or isn't it true.

Comment: Hi user1098185, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Could you expand on your question? What reason do you have to believe this is true or not true? Where else have you looked to try to find the answer, and what didn't you understand about what you found? etc.

Comment: Hi, and thanks! My teacher told me today that the mangnetic fields goes from the plus to the minus. A picture can show what i mean:
http://tinypic.com/r/ifoqo9/6

Comment: What are "plus" and "minus"?

Comment: Dipole. The magnetic charges. Dont know what to call it, but if you look at the picture you will see it. The round circle with + and -

Comment: I think if you look carefully at the picture you mentioned, it's showing the electric field, not magnetic. The $E$ label and arrow are the big hit ($E$ is for electric field). The $+$ and $-$ would then be electric charges. Also, $+$ and $-$ are not normally used for magnetic fields, which are always loops. The $N$ and $S$ designations, indicating loops flowing "out" or "in" from bunched-up bundles of such loops, are used instead.

Comment: @TerryBollinger: your comment is clearly the correct answer. Can you copy/paste it in as an answer so it can be accepted. I get twitchy when I see questions left unanswered :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think if you look carefully at the picture you mentioned, it's showing the electric field, not magnetic. The $E$ label and arrow are the big hit ($E$ is for electric field). The $+$ and $−$ would then be electric charges. Also, $+$ and $−$ are not normally used for magnetic fields, which are always loops. The $N$ and $S$ designations, indicating loops flowing "out" or "in" from bunched-up bundles of such loops, are used instead.